# ModuleNotFoundError, even thought it exist, and is installed

Tags: python, django

I tried makemigrations and i get:

> from SocialNetwork.Accounts.models import User
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'SocialNetwork.Accounts''=

I made a few applications, installed it in settings, and even pycharm sees it, but I get the error shown above.

This is my project structure:

```
-SocialNetwork (main directory)
  -SocialNetwork (project package)
      -Accounts
       -__init__.py
       -admin.py
       -apps.py
       -models.py
       -tests.py
       -urls.py
       -views.py
     -Chats
       -__init__.py
       -admin.py
       -apps.py
       -models.py
       -tests.py
       -urls.py
       -views.py
     -Other apps
     -SocialNetwork (settings, wsgi, urls etc)
```

And tried install models from account in chats:

```py
from django.db import models

from SocialNetwork.Accounts.models import User


class Chat(models.Model):

    firstUser = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    secondUser = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I doubt that it will be helpful but i can write models from user:

```py
class User(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    phone = models.PhoneNumberField()
    dateBirth = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True
```

I have been sitting with this for 2 hours, what can I do in this case? Maybe something more with settings or structure? But structure seems be as always in django projects. Any help will be appreciated, I am new in django.

Comment: Are you able to make the folder structure and import lines work if you *don't* make a Django project?

Comment: I am not sure, but you talk about, can i work with modules without django? Or maybe my project structure in description was not accurate enough?

Comment: Uhm sorry, this was not question really, this was my language mistake. This was not the question, i know that i can work with. It comes to something different, nevermind. I just don't exactly understand the question first

Comment: Use `from Accounts.models import User` instead. When you write `SocialNetwork.Accounts` it tries to look into the app that has the same name (by default created by django when starting a project)

Comment: Could a `__init__.py` file be missing from `SocialNetwork`, making the module invisible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an empty `__init__.py` to your `SocialNetwork` folder so it can be recognized as a package. Check the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages).

And do `from Accounts.models import User` instead.

Comment: I made a package from it but it still doesn't work.

Comment: @Peteros527 did you add the social network app to `INSTALLED_APPS`?

Comment: Yep, i added all of this apps to settings as always

Comment: Have you tried relative imports? Like `from ..SocialNetwork.Accounts.models import User`? Do you have another level on your project? Maybe it should be `from <project_name>.SocialNetwork.Accounts.models import ...` instead.

Comment: Yes, i have tried both, relative and absolute. Maybe i will paste full error message

Comment: When i use "from SocialNetwork.SocialNetwork " then i have only files as settings, wsgi, urls etc. But when i use "from SocialNetwork. " then after (dot) i can import apps, after this, modules from apps etc. But it still doesn't work.

Comment: Do you have two different `SocialNetwork` folders at the same level? That can't be right. Rename your app to be different than the core project folder, and update your installed apps

Comment: In the main normal directory, i have SocialNetwork package where i have apps and next SocialNetwork package where i have settings, urls etc. At the same level i have apps and SocialNetwork package with settings. Maybe i should use more complex formula to write apps in settings? But i have as almost always people have.

Comment: Do `from Accounts.models import User` and if that throws error post it

Comment: It work, sorry, now i know that i can't trust ide, cos this show errors everywhere, but migrations doesn't, thank you very much, thanks for patience.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
from Accounts.models import User
```

Comment: No, thank you very much, the advice above helped